# How to reuse a page layout in another page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout

[image]I have created a custom page layout using module and .aspx page.

I have uploaded it in the `_catalog/masterpage` folder. It gets uploaded in the folder, but I want to set that custom page layout in my application as default.

How to do that?

Comment: Do you want the created layout will be appear in the list of layouts seen while creating the new page?

Comment: Ya.. I want to select my custom page layout when creating a page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have to **Publish** your **Page Layout** then you can see the page layout in the drop-down list.
- Just **edit your page layout in the browser** and set proper name and then **publish** it.
- Once you have published this page-layout, You can see your page layout while creating a new page.
- Hope this will help you.

Comment: Already Its published but the custom page layout is not displayed. I will attach screenshot in my question

Comment: Screen shot does not explain anything.

Comment: I have published the page layout but that custom page layout doesn't displayed in the list which you mentioned in eVT answer

Comment: Did you find the answer? if yes then post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
YOURWEB/_layouts/15/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx
```

Under Page Layouts add your New Page Layout

Under New Page Default Settings check your new Page Layout

[image]

----edit

try this

YOURWEB/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Find your new Page Layout and click edit properties

Under **Associated Content Type** check your Content Type (If is _Hidden you will not view that page layout under settings)

Comment: In that list I didn't see my custom page layout.. Actually it get uploaded in _catalog/masterpage folder

Comment: check edited answer